# fabric block cloudify bootstrap

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, fabric, bootstrapping, cloudify

I am trying to bootstrap an instance of CentOS with cloudify on AWS EC2, but i can't get that happen because i am always interrupted by a fabric error that says: `fabric_plugin.tasks.run_module_task' -> Needed to prompt for a connection or sudo password (host: X.X.X.X), but abort-on-prompts was set to True`.

I made a simple YAML file to configure the AWS bootstrap, and the .pem public key created after I run the bootstrap command, so basically the fabric should use it with the CentOS EC2 username without prompting for password.

my input.YAML file:

```
aws_access_key_id: 'XX'
aws_secret_access_key: 'XXXX'

image_id: 'ami-6e37a25e' #ami-e48d6ad7' #ami-45f7ed24' 
instance_type: 't2.micro'

ssh_key_filename: '~/.ssh/manager-cle.pem'
agent_private_key_path: ''~/.ssh/client-cle.pem'

manager_security_group_name: 'cloudify-manager-security-group'
agent_security_group_name: 'cloudify-agent-security-group'
manager_server_name: 'cloudify-manager-server'

manager_keypair_name: 'manager-key'
agent_keypair_name: 'agent-key'
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually you are prompted for sudo because one of the following is not valid:

1. **User** - make sure that the user you are using exists on the target machine. The user we supply is centos, because that is the default user on the AMI we suggest. I see you've provided your own. I would check what value you are using for "ssh_user" input.
2. **Key** - make sure the path to the key is correct.
3. You are using the **IP** of a different machine.

Comment: I already tried with user centos (and ubuntu for the ubuntu image), but still have the same probleme.

For key's, they are created by the "cfy bootstrap" command in that path, i verified it.

For the IP, it's the cloudify who negociate the ip with the amazon server, so there is now way i can put a wrong IP address because it's automatic.